# How to setup which Symfony environment is used by unit tests?

Tags: symfony, phpunit, environment-variables, travis-ci, symfony-3.4

I am trying to setup a new Symfony environment named `travis` to run unit tests in a Travis container.

I setup this environment to distinguish it from `prod` and from `dev`.

Currently, I have:

- a `SYMFONY_ENV=travis` environment variable setup in Travis
- a `config_travis.yml` that contains my configuration for the Travis environment
- a `app_travis.php` which specify the environment to load
- a `.travis.yml`:

>

```
language: php

php:
  - "7.2.17"

services:
  - mysql

install:
  - composer install --no-interaction
  - echo "USE mysql;\nUPDATE user SET password=PASSWORD('${MYSQL_PASSWORD}') WHERE user='root';\nFLUSH PRIVILEGES;\n" | mysql -u root
  - ./bin/console doctrine:database:create --env=travis
  - ./bin/console doctrine:migration:migrate --env=travis --no-interaction

script:
  - ./vendor/bin/simple-phpunit
```

My project looks like this:

[image: screenshot of the folders tree of my project]

Some examples of tests I'm running:

`UserTest.php` which tests the `User.php` model:

```
<?php
namespace Tests\AppBundle\Entity;

use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use AppBundle\Entity\Responsibility;

class UserTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testId()
    {
        $user = new User();
        $id = $user->getId();
        $this->assertEquals(-1, $id);
    }
}
```

`LoginControllerTest.php` which tests the `LoginController.php` controller:

```
<?php
namespace Tests\AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;
use Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Cookie;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class LoginControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    /*
     * Test the login form
     * Logins with (admin, password : a)
     */
    public function testLogin()
    {
        // Create a new client to browse the app
        $client = static::createClient();
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/login');
        $this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode(), "Unexpected HTTP status code for GET ");
        // Get the form
        $form = $crawler->selectButton('Connexion')->form();
        // Fill the login form input
        $form['_username']->setValue('admin');
        $form['_password']->setValue('a');
        // Send the form
        $client->submit($form);
        $crawler = $client->followRedirect();
        $this->assertContains(
                'Bienvenue admin.' ,
                $client->getResponse()->getContent()
        );

        return array($client,$crawler);
    }
}
```

My problem is: all the command run into the `travis` environment, except the unit tests. I want to be able to run the unit tests in `dev` env on my computer but in `travis` env in the Travis container.

How can I setup my PHPUnit so that it can run in `travis` environment and use my `config_travis.yml` file?

Comment: How do you unit tests look like? Do they somehow boot the Symfony kernel?

Comment: I updated my question with example of my tests, does it answer your question or didn't I understand it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPUnit uses an environment variable called `APP_ENV` to determines which environment is used. I had to create this environment variable in Travis.

[image: screenshot of the Travis environment variables setting showing the environment variables I created]

Answer (score 1):

The `createClient()` method of the `WebTestCase` calls the `bootKernel()` method from the `KernelTestCase` which in turn calls `createKernel()`. In `createKernel()` there is the following code which determines in which environment the kernel should be booted:

```
if (isset($options['environment'])) {
    $env = $options['environment'];
} elseif (isset($_ENV['APP_ENV'])) {
    $env = $_ENV['APP_ENV'];
} elseif (isset($_SERVER['APP_ENV'])) {
    $env = $_SERVER['APP_ENV'];
} else {
    $env = 'test';
}
```

So in your case exporting the `APP_ENV` variable in your `config_travis.yml` file and setting it to `travis` should solve it.